# CodeBuild set No VPC using aws codebuild cli

Tags: aws-codebuild

How can I set **No VPC** using aws codebuild cli?
I tried using:

```
aws codebuild update-project \
  --name <PROJECT_NAME> \
  --vpc-config vpcId='',subnets='',securityGroupIds=''
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
Invalid length for parameter vpcConfig.subnets[0], value: 0, valid range: 1-inf
Invalid length for parameter vpcConfig.vpcId, value: 0, valid range: 1-inf
Invalid length for parameter vpcConfig.securityGroupIds[0], value: 0, valid range: 1-inf
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `null` instead of empty string `''`:

```
--vpc-config vpcId=null,subnets=null,securityGroupIds=null
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that worked for me

`aws codebuild update-project --name <projName> --vpc-config {}`